# Winforms How to write code to resize a window (and move at the same time)?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, user-controls, window

I'm making a custom window. When you resize a window from the left or the top, the window technically moves and resizes at the same time. I need to create this effect. I didnt post my code because its not even close, the window just jumps around the screen really fast... But here is the code I use for resizing and moving:

```
private void SetMousePosition(MouseEventArgs Position) {
    MousePos = Position.Location;
}
private void SetRightPosition(MouseEventArgs Position) {
    MouseDif = new Point(PointToClient(MousePosition).X - this.Width, PointToClient(MousePosition).Y - this.Height);
}
private void StartDrag(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        int x = this.Left + e.X - MousePos.X;
        int y = this.Top + e.Y - MousePos.Y;
        this.Location = new Point(x, y);
    }
}
private void StartRightResize(MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        title.Text = PointToClient(MousePosition).X.ToString();
        int x = PointToClient(MousePosition).X - MouseDif.X;
        if (x < 60) x = 60;
        this.Width = x;
    }
}
```

This is the code I use just for dragging, and just for resizing from the right border. I just need to be able to use the left border to resize... I also need this to be able to work with a user control, and a custom window, i dont know id that makes sense though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the [`SetBounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0tayb1b.aspx) method, which allows you to change size and position in a single operation?  That should prevent the control from getting redrawn as often.

Of course, you might need to make a picture of the control (`BitBlt`), hide the control, and resize using that placeholder, then when the resize finishes, set the bounds of the real control and make it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:

[Drawing Custom Borders in Windows Forms](http://geekswithblogs.net/kobush/articles/CustomBorderForms3.aspx)